# C++17 std::async non blocking execution

Tags: c++, c++17

I have created this C++17 code that mimics something that I need.

```
std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

auto a = std::async([]() -> int {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 5 });
    return 2;
});
std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;

std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;
```

The thread sleeps here but in real example I do heavy operations and I return an integer which can be 0, 1 or 7. This is my output:

```
start
2
stop
```

This is good! This code will not freeze my UI. I know that `a.get()` is a blocking operation but is there a way to be non blocking?

In other words: instead of

```
start
2
stop
```

can I get as output

```
start
stop
2
```

using `async`? I need async because I have found online that it is useful when return a value is needed. It is also easy to read! I do not want to use `std::packaged_task`, promises, futures etc because `async` is easy.

If it cannot be non blocking can I use something else?

Comment: It has to block because it needs time to calculate its things! You could wrap this in a thread and detatch it

Comment: What is detatch? I cannot find it in async.

Comment: I don't understand how you want `get()` to be non-blocking. You want to *get* a value, so it has to be blocking, no?

Comment: My comment was: create a thread (std::thread), detatch it and call the get() inside that thread. In this way you'll get the output that you want

Comment: Alberto Miola can you please write the code?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking to have the result printed when it's done, regardless of who else is printing at the time. It seems like you don't even need async here, you can just have a separate thread that prints the result whenever it calculates one. Ordinary I wouldn't recommend this but if you don't have anything using the output, it might be okay.

Comment: Rakete1111 I was wondering if there was a way to not block the caller thread

Comment: @randomguy7 I understand but it seems like you are using the wrong abstraction. If you want the new thread to be independent, then `std::async` is the wrong function to use. The caller has to block when you call `get()` if the result is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will output what you need:

```
std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

std::thread{
    []() {
        auto a = std::async([]() -> int {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 5 });
            return 2;
        });

        std::cout << a.get() << std::endl;
    }
}.detach();

std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;
```

---

If I were you I wouldn't use `async` at all. If you just need to display a value and you don't want to block, you should do something else. For example:

```
std::cout << "start" << std::endl;

std::thread{
    []() {
        //do here what you need and print the result
    }
}.detach();

/* ... or ...
auto t = std::thread{ ... };
t.detach();
*/

std::cout << "stop" << std::endl;
```

See that `detach()` makes the new thread "independent" and doesn't block while `join()` blocks. The point is that `async` **must** block because if it has to do an operation that takes a lot of time, it has to spend that time!

Comment: It probably makes sense to synchronize output.