# non-blocking call of std::async: how is this version dangerous?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Some time ago I was looking for a way to invoke `std::async` without the need of storing `std::future`, thus not blocking the execution at the end of the scope. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454793/whats-the-c-11-way-to-fire-off-an-asynchronous-task-and-forget-about-it/56834117#56834117) which uses a captured `std::shared_ptr` for an `std::future`, therefore allowing to make a nonblocking call to `std::async`.

Another way of deferring a destructor invocation is to prevent it from to be called at all. This can be achieved with in-place construction with `operator new`.

Consider this version that uses a static thread local storage for an in-place constructed `std::future<void>`:

```
template <class F>
void call_async(F&& fun) {
    thread_local uint8_t buf[sizeof(std::future<void>)] = {0};
    auto fut = new(buf) std::future<void>();
    *fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [fun]() {
        fun();
    });
}
```

This version will not produce any heap-allocation related overhead, but it seems very illegal, though I am not sure why in particular.

I am aware that it is UB to use an object before it has been constructed, which is not the case. I am not sure why not calling `delete` in this case would resolve in UB (for heap allocation it is not UB).

Possible problems that I see:

- calling a constructor on one object multiple times
- race condition when modifying the state (inner `std::promise` I suppose)

https://ideone.com/C44cfe

**UPDATE**

Constructing an object in the static storage directly (as has mentioned IlCapitano in the comments) will block each time a move assignment is called (shared state will be destroyed blocking the thread which has removed last reference to it).

Not calling a destructor will case a leak because of not released references to the shared state.

Comment: So, basically, `std::future` is not really relevant to the question. The question is is it valid to  `void func() { char buf[sizeof(T)]; new (buf) T(); }` construct an object with placement new on stack and not call ever destructor at all? Because as for async: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130091/c17-stdasync-non-blocking-execution/52130280

Comment: No. The question mentions several possible problems, and I would like to know if there&#39;s something I missed. Regarding destructor: I&#39;ve mentioned it already: for heap allocated objects destructor will also not be called without delete.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've forgot to address you, in the comment above. 
Your link is about detaching a constructed thread. Thread construction is way too slower than calling std::async

Comment: Are you intending to call this only once per thread?

Comment: @Caleth no. At first it was `static`, but then I thought of making it `thread local` to get rid of race condition for in-place construction in shared memory. One thread might call it as many times as it wants: in `main` starting 50 asynchronous calls.

Comment: You could probably use `thread_local std::future<void> fut` to avoid not calling the desturctor.

Comment: @IlCapitano this looks better. You mean "to avoid calling the destructor"

Comment: @IlCapitano the only question is: does move assignment force to wait for previous async call completion? cppreference doesn't mention it. If it did, you would possibly get blocking on next asynchronous call.

Comment: You could just use `new` to allocate the `future` instance. Obviously, this leaks, but if you think about it, you will find that your version is not guaranteed to not leak. `future` could allocate additional resources which your versions leaks. Actually, it is meant to hold a reference to a resource! Also, other code in the implementation could reference the `future` instance so overwriting it would not just leak but cause errors like invalid/dangling references.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that is a very solid point. I suggest you add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour to end the lifetime of a non-trivial object without calling it's destructor, which happens as soon as there is a second `call_async` invocation.

"heap-allocation related overhead" is a misnomer if the only alternative is undefined behaviour. The `future` returned by `async` has to live *somewhere*.

The updated code has defined behaviour: it waits for the previous invocation to be done before launching the next one.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is the new implementation ok?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik OK in the sense that it has defined behaviour. It doesn't do what you want, there is no way of having *multiple* `async` calls in-flight without having space for *each* of the resulting `future`s

Comment: I was wondering if a blocking occurred on move assignment, since on cppreference it is not mentioned as in destructor: `Releases any shared state and move-assigns the contents of other to *this. After the assignment, other.valid() == false and this->valid() will yield the same value as other.valid() before the assignment.`

Comment: The shared state in a future that was sourced from `async` blocks in it's destructor

Comment: _It's undefined behaviour to end the lifetime of a non-trivial object without calling it's destructor_ Any wording supporting this?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "A program is not required to call the destructor of an object to end its lifetime if the object is trivially-destructible or if the program does not rely on the side effects of the destructor." [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) And placement-newing over an existing object ends it's lifetime

Comment: IIUC there is [tentative agreement](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2342#issuecomment-436158090) that this wording should be [removed](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2342/files).

Comment: Ok, that would mean that it is defined behaviour if it were user code. But the standard doesn't specify how the completion of the future is signaled, so it's implementation-defined? I'd still not want to rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `std::async` and ignoring the result sounds like "fire and forget". The simplest way to do that is to not use `std::async`, but to create a detached thread:

```
std::thread thr(func, data...);
thr.detach();
```

Comment: it is the easiest, but very expensive. `std::async` uses thread pool which is way faster

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik -- `std::async` is not required to use a thread pool, and `std::thread` is allowed to use one.. If you have compiler-specific reasons for the approach you're talking about you should spell them out.